# Is it possible to resize multiple image files with Irfanview?

Tags: irfanview

I've got Irfanview 4.28.  I've also got several .jpg files, which are all pretty large (many 4000 x 3000, and other sizes).  I'd like to resize them all to something like 800x600, is it possible to do several files at once with Irfanview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IrfanView has a feature to batch resize images. Just follow the instructions given [here](http://www.ofzenandcomputing.com/zanswers/1028).

[image]